# How to get Top Parent in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have 2 columns in a table, Parent and Child. I want to get Top Parent for each row. The data I have is somewhat mentioned below.

```
PARENT CHILD
A01    B01
A01    C01
B01    D02
B01    E02
C01    F02
X01    Y01
Y01    Z02
Z02    D02
```

Then result I am expecting is

```
TOP PARENT PARENT CHILD
A01        A01    B01
A01        A01    C01
A01        B01    D02
A01        B01    E02
A01        C01    F02
X01        X01    Y01
X01        Y01    Z02
X01        Z02    D02
```

I know there is a function in Oracle **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** which I can use to get the path and Top Parent of any hierarchal structure but not sure how to do in Postgresql. Can anyone guide me or just maybe give me a hint to start with ?

Not sure if this is helpful but that's what I've been trying so far

```
with recursive cte as (
    select br2."PARENT" , br2."CHILD" 
    from table1 br2
    inner join cte on cte."PARENT" = br2."CHILD" 
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep top parent in a separate column

```
with recursive rcte as(
  select PARENT top, PARENT, CHILD
  from table1 t1
  where not exists (select 1 from table1 t2 where t1.parent = t2.child)

  union all

  select top, p.PARENT, p.CHILD
  from rcte 
  join table1 p on p.parent = rcte.child
)
select * 
from  rcte
order by top, parent;
```